# How to send a patch api request using a variable

Tags: api, patch, guzzle, userid, zoom-sdk

I am trying to update a user(s) type in the Zoom conference application using their API. I use PATCH as per their documentation, and this works when I hard code the userId in the URL, but I need to use an array variable instead because multiple users will need to be updated at once.

This code works with the manually entered userId.
The userId and bearer code are made up for the purpose of this question.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$client = new Client();

$response = $client->PATCH('https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/jkdflg4589jlmfdhw7', [

'headers' => [
'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
'Authorization' => 'Bearer my token goes here',
],

'body' => json_encode([
    'type' => '1',
])
]);

$body = $response->getBody() ;
$string = $body->getContents(); 
$json = json_decode($string);
```

This way the code works and changes my user's type to 1.

The following code is the one that doesn't work.
In the Zoom API reference there is a test section and the userId can be added in a tab called Settings under the field: Path Parameters.

https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/users/userupdate

Hence I can add the userId there and when I run it, it actually replaces {userId} in the URL with the actual userId into the url patch command.

Hence from this ->

PATCH [https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/{userId}](https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/%7BuserId%7D)

It becomes this after all transformations, scripts,
and variable replacements are run.

PATCH https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/jkdflg4589jlmfdhw7

However, when I try it in my code it doesn't work, I don't know where to add the path params. I am more used to PHP but I'll use whatever I can to make it work. Also I would like userId to be a variable that may contain 1 or more userIds (array).

This is my code that doesn't work:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$client = new Client();

$response = $client->PATCH('https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/{userId}', [

'params' => [
'userId' => 'jkdflg4589jlmfdhw7',
],

'headers' => [
'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
'Authorization' => 'Bearer my token goes here',
],

'body' => json_encode([
    'type' => '1',
])
]);

$body = $response->getBody() ;
$string = $body->getContents(); 
$json = json_decode($string);
```

My code fails with error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `PATCH https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/%7BuserId%7D` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: {"code":1001,"message":"User not exist: {userId}"}
in /home/.../Zoom_API_V2/guzzle_response/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113 Stack trace:
#0 /home/.../Zoom_API_V2/guzzle_response/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(66): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#1 /home/.../Zoom_API_V2/guzzle_response/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#2 /home/.../Zoom_API_V2/guzzle_response/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array)
#3 /home/.../publ in /home/.../Zoom_API_V2/guzzle_response/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 113
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then this is basic string concatenation in PHP that you are trying to do

```
$userId = 'jkdflg4589jlmfdhw7';

$response = $client->PATCH('https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/' . $userId, [
    // other options
]);
```

> However, when I try it in my code it doesn't work, I don't know where to add the path params.

You add URL path in the first argument, since path is part of the URL. You can however set query parameters (e.g. for GET requests) and form data (e.g. for POST form requests) through Guzzle options, but not the path.

> Also I would like userId to be a variable that may contain 1 or more userIds (array).

Using just a simple `implode` to convert an array to a comma separated list should work, but the API point you linked to does not seem to support multiple user IDs.

```
$userId = ['jkdflg4589jlmfdhw7', 'asdfa123sdfasdf'];

$response = $client->PATCH('https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/' . implode(',', $userId), [
    // other options
]);
```

Comment: Thanks ncla, I will test out your solution